# Using two Ajax calls to post then retrieve data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am currently trying to firstly post the name of the user that I am trying to retrieve from the database to my php code using ajax.  Then in the success part of the call I am trying to make a function to retrieve data from a database which matches the name of the user the I previously sent to the page, however no data is coming back to the javascript code.

Here is the function with my ajax calls.

```
function checkPatientAnswers(event) {

  window.open("../src/clinicreview.php", "_self");
  var patientname = event.data.patientname;
  var dataToSend = 'patientname=' + patientname;
  var clinicquestions = getQuestionsForClinic();
  var answers = [];

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../src/getselectedpatient.php",
    data: dataToSend,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {

      $.ajax({
        url: "../src/getselectedpatient.php",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(row) {
          answers = row;
          console.log(row);
        }

      })
    }
  })
  console.log(answers);
  for (i in clinicquestions) {
    $('#patientanswers').append("<h2>" + clinicquestions[i] + " = " + answers[i]);

  }
  $('#patientanswers').append("Patient Status = " + answers[answers.length - 1]);
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php


session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("devweb2015.cis.strath.ac.uk","uname","mypass") or ('Failed to connect' . mysql_error());


$currentdb = mysql_select_db('yyb11163', $con) or die('Failed to connect' . mysql_error());

$patientname = $_POST['patientname'];
$_SESSION['patient'] = $POST['patientname'];


$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT question1, question2, question3, question4, patient_status FROM patient_info where real_name = '$patientname'");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo json_encode($data);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: can you add dataType to the first ajax and also console.log the result in the first ajax to see if something is returned :)

Comment: no return on first or on second attempt?  try outputting javascript to console and also have your php serverside save a log file, so that you know if it ran at all and/or where you stopped.  - @guradio - seems like i was watching you type.  ha!

Comment: The success function on the first attempt ran so I assume that the first call was run.  But an empty array is sent back in the second call

Comment: @tonygil those are the first things that  came to my mind when i read the question :)

Comment: May I ask why you need to store `$_SESSION['patient']` at all? Please see my answer shortly for what I am 99.945% positive you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Was just to show the name of the person they were viewing, but I can do with with JavaScript so will take it out.

Comment: `window.open("../src/clinicreview.php", "_self");` will replace the page you are on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
var dataToSend = {'patientname':patientname};

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "../src/getselectedpatient.php",
    data : dataToSend,
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    success: function(result) {

        console.log(result);

    }
})
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['patient'] = $POST['patientname'];

$con = mysql_connect("devweb2015.cis.strath.ac.uk","uname","mypass") or ('Failed to connect' . mysql_error());

$currentdb = mysql_select_db('yyb11163', $con) or die('Failed to connect' . mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT question1, question2, question3, question4, patient_status FROM patient_info where real_name = '".$_POST['patientname']."'");

$data = mysql_fetch_row($query);

mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

---

For the record, I do not condone the use of your `mysql_*` shenanigans. It has been completely **REMOVED** in PHP 7 and don't try telling me that you will ride PHP 5 till death do you part.

Secondly, you are 8000% open to SQL injection.

I understand that you are most likely just a student at a school in the UK but if your teacher/professor is OK with your code then you are not getting your money's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set `data` on the second call:

```
     $.ajax({
            url : "../src/getselectedpatient.php",
            data : result,
```

or `result.id`or whatever.